# Storing into variable a result of boolean expression

Tags: bash

Is it possible to continuously store a result of boolean expression into a variable?

Example

```
ret=0
for each in aCollection do
    executeSomeCommand;
    # vvv compare stored value against a returned value and store it again
    ret=$ret || $?;
done;
[[ ret = 0 ]] && echo "success"
```

The problem is that if `$?` is `1`, then `$ret` still contains zero

```
ret=0
echo $ret # --> 0
ret=$ret || 1
echo $ret # --> 0 (should be 1)
```

Comment: What is the point, it will change every loop anyway. All you are attempting to do is  compare the return value from `executeSomeCommand` with the value from the previous loop. Why not just set `ret=$?` ? In either case ret will equal the last returned value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a grouping/order of operations problem.  When you do

```
ret=$ret || 1
```

it is first doing `ret=$ret` and then taking the result of that and doing an `||` with `1` then ignoring the result of that.  So the only part of the assignment you're doing is assigning `ret` to itself again.

What you want is to do the `$ret || 1` part and store the result, so you need parens like

```
ret=$(($ret || 1))
```

Comment: Not just parentheses, but you need an arithmetic expression to perform the boolean OR, rather than create two separate commands using the `||` list operator. Only the fact that an assignment always succeeds prevents you from running the almost certainly non-existent command named by the value of `$?`.