# Can I store the evaluation of a regex expression into a variable?

Tags: regex, bash

I receive a string that can be either all numeric dash-separated, and in that case it is **acceptable** to me (e.g. `123423-56788-456522-34245`) or not all numeric and still dash-separated, and in that case it is **not acceptable** to me (e.g. `123423-56788-shelve-34245`).

In order to determine whether the string is acceptable or not, I have built the following if block:

```
REGEX_FOR_ONLY_NUMERICAL_CHANGELISTS='^[0-9-]+$'
if [[ ${BUILD_ID} =~ ${REGEX_FOR_ONLY_NUMERICAL_CHANGELISTS} ]]
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

The above if block works fine. However, if I would be programming into another language (for example, Java), I would be assigning the evaluation directly into the variable. For example:

```
int a = 3; 
int b = 5; 
boolean test = (a < b);
```

The above `test` would be `true`: I would be evaluating the expression (`a < b`) and store its result into the variable `test` in one line.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the same in Bash. Looking around the web, I haven't found many examples. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652881/storing-into-variable-a-result-of-boolean-expression), I have realized that if I do this:

```
bash$ false_expression=$((2 == 4))
bash$ true_expression=$((2 == 2))
```

... the two variables assume values `0` and `1` respectively. It's not exactly `true` or `false`, but I could still accept it. 
However, I don't seem to be able to do the same with my expression because if I do this:

```
InvalidCL=123423-56788-shelve-34245
MyRegex='^[0-9-]+$'
FalseExpression=$((${InvalidCL} =~ ${MyRegex}))
```

...the third assignment raises this error:

```
-bash: 123423-56788-shelve-34245 =~ ^[0-9-]+$: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=~ ^[0-9-]+$")
```

I'm not a real bash expert, so my question (hoping it's not too silly) is: *is it possible to assign the evaluation to a variable?* I can see that my `if [[ myExpression ]]` is evaluated as `true`, so I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to assign this evaluation to a variable... Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it with one assignment then you could do it like:

```
FalseExpression=$( [[ "$InvalidCL" =~ $MyRegex ]] && echo 1 || echo 0)
```

where `1` stands for `true` and `0` for `false`. Keep in mind, though, that this is not the traditional Bash way. A result of `0` in Bash indicates no error, i.e., if the expression evaluates to `true` then you get an exit status of:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Notice, the use of single `(` which stand for command substitution, whereas the `((` in your example evaluate a mathematical expression.

Traditionally, one would probably do it like this:

```
$ [[ "$InvalidCL" =~ $MyRegex ]]
$ FalseExpression=$?
```

Bash stores the exit status of the last opereation in '$?', which behaves in an opposite way as the `$(())` operator. If the expression is `true` than `$?` will store `0` while $(()) will return `1`. The latter is probably more familiar if you are coming from a C background. I suggest to not mix those approaches. It can be quite hard to debug a script if one result can have different meanings.

Comment: No need for `&&` or `||`; just `$( [[ ... ]]; echo $? )` will suffice.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but OP posted: `true_expression=$((2 == 2))` from which I concluded that he wants a `1` to indicate `true`, hence the conditional operators to assign the "proper" value.

Comment: Good point. It depends on the context in which `FalseExpression` will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer nautical. I like the approach, but if I define `ValidCL=123423-56788-456522-34245` and then run `TrueExpression=$( [[ "$ValidCL" =~ "$MyRegex" ]] && echo 1 || echo 0)`, the value of `TrueExpression` will still be `0` whereas it is supposed to be `1`. Same with the second solution you showed :(

Comment: P.s. I clarify: no matter whether the expression is true or false, it will always print the same result. It's not a matter of switching the 0 and the 1 (I understood that here we're tracking the success - 0 - or insuccess - 1).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Sorry, my bad. Do NOT put quotation marks around `$MyRegex`. See my updated post.

Comment: @nautical now it works, thank you. I'll be waiting a little bit more to see if new answers come up, then I will choose my favorite one. But a +1 is well deserved in any case for both the solutions and the explanations :)

Comment: Gone for this, it's clear, one line only and especially easily customizable from 0/1 to true/false which is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
[[ ${BUILD_ID} =~ ${REGEX_FOR_ONLY_NUMERICAL_CHANGELISTS} ]]
val=$?
```

to avoid invoking a subshell.  Again, val is 0 on success and 1 on failure.

Comment: `val = $?` Bash does not allow space before and after the `=`.

Comment: As commented on Paul's answer, even your works fine but I find it a bit hard to understand for a first reader of the code. I'll wait a bit to see if other answers show a clearer solution before to accept an answer, but a +1 is deserved :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a direct single-line assignment to a numeric boolean, you can use a "not" operator in your test.

> I ***strongly*** recommend you add some explanatory comments around this.

```
# assign an integer BOOLEAN value from the test for a match
# the ! means NOT, inverts a 0/1 OS exit code from [[ ]]
match="$( [[ ! "$string" =~ $pattern ]]; echo $?; )"  
# now $match is 1 (TRUE) if it *matched* the pattern
```

For better clarity, make a function with the comments in it to encapsulate the logic, and call *that* from one line.

```
boolMatch() { 
   local match str="$1" pat="$2"

   # test the match
   [[ "$str" =~ $pat ]]

   # invert the return to a boolean value
   match=$(( ! $? ))

   # pass back the boolean
   echo $match
}

$: boolMatch foo bar
0
$: boolMatch foo foo
1
$: match=$( boolMatch $stringToCheck $patternToUse )
```

Comment: This works fine. However, as you say, it's a bit hard to understand for a first reader of the code. I'll wait a bit to see if other answers show a clearer solution before to accept an answer, but a +1 is deserved :)

Comment: Had another few minutes so I expanded my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Paul, much appreciated. I will go with the other answer just because I find it clearer to read for someone else touching the code, but this is also very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out how to work around getting the *boolean return value* of the regular expression match.

Regarding the phrasing of the actual question, I would like to point out that the evaluation results of a regex expression actually automatically get stored in an environment variable in bash. The `$BASH_REMATCH` array stores the entire match at index `0` and the capturing groups at their respective indices. See: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

The number of elements in this array can also, perhaps more comfortably than the manual assignment from `$?`, be used as an indicator of success of the match. If `${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}` is zero, the last regular expression did not match.

You get the error message you cited because regular expression matching syntax is defined only within the `[[ ... ]]` construct, not in `$(( ... ))`arithmetic evaluation, so when it sees the `=` it thinks you must be trying some sort of assignment.

Comment: This was the actual first answer I started. :D